# Toggle a Boolean Value in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am accessing my `firebase` database from my android app. I need to implement `like` functionality like facebook. So when the user presses like button, if the post is already liked it gets unliked and vice versa. For that purpose, I am first checking if the `liked` boolean field is true in the firebase and if it is, then update it to false and vice versa. My current approach includes reading the `liked` field and then writing it (doing 2 DB Calls).

Is there any native solution provided by Firebase for this?

> Toggling a boolean value in Firebase Database

Comment: I've answered this question with one of way I could think of. But I want to ask you, why didn't you listen to like/not like node first to determinate its value. Then based on that value, you decide the new value is true or false. That previous listener's value will also be changed, so it will work no matter how many time the button is clicked

Answer (score 3):

This way is a bit nasty and not very good actually, but it work and fastest way (I think).

Instead of `boolean`, make your parameter `integer`. Every time the like button clicked, add `+1` value into it, and whenever you read that data, you just need to confirm if it's odd or even. Odd is for like, even for not like, or vice versa.